# Excel VBA: Worksheet_Change not firing at all after checking many settings

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have searched numerous articles and websites trying to figure out why my Worksheet_Change sub is not working. Here is the code (it doesn't get more basic than this):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Changed:" & Target.Address
End Sub
```

Nothing happens when I change a cell on the one-and-only sheet in the workbook. Also, I have verified ?Application.EnableEvents returns "True" in the Immediate window. I have looked into the File> Options > Trust Center settings, Macros are enabled, I have Microsoft Scripting Runtime checked in the References list. Ultimately, this is what I want my code to do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Check the value of the C5 cell
    If Target.Value = "L-39" Then
        With Sheets("Flight Summary")
            .Range("F3").Value = N4351J
            .Range("I11:I23").ClearContents
            .Range("D25:D32").ClearContents
            .Range("D24").Value = 1
            .Range("B38:I38").ClearContents
        End With 'Sheets("Flight Summary")
    End If 'Target.Value = "L-39"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Of course, I need the simple code to work before I get the next set of code work. It appears the Worksheet_Change subroutine is not firing at all and I can't figure out why after hours of research and checking. I am on a Windows 10 machine with Office 365 for Enterprise. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this code in a sheet code module?

Comment: Maybe for some reasons events are disabled? Enter `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window

Comment: @BigBen, no it is in a module. Perhaps I need to put it on the Sheet?

Comment: @FunThomas, I have checked that and ?Application.EnableEvents returns "True" in the Immediate window.  Application Events are on.

Comment: You need to put the code in the sheet module of the sheet you want to supervise.

Comment: @FunThomas: Thanks, that was it.  Wow, I feel pretty silly. Thanks for pointing out the one thing I didn't try!

Comment: ^^^^^ and once you fix that, if you're putting in the code module of the sheet named "Flight Summary", then you can change `Sheets("Flight Summary")` to `Me`. If "Flight Summary" is a separate sheet however, then you don't need to disable/enable events.

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for the tips! There is only one (1) sheet in the workbook, so I will still need to disable/enable events to prevent the code from getting into a perpetual loop.  I wasn't aware of the Me verbiage, thanks!